# Motion in a plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I have a question which says that a particle moves in the $xy$ plane according to the relation $x = Asin(qt )$ and $y= A - Acos(qt)  $, where A and q are constants.

I have to figure out the distance in an interval of time t.  I tried it several times but could not get it right as i did the vector addition of the displacements in the x and the y directions.  After that i asked  my teacher and he said that the particle will move in a circle but he didnt explain why.

Can someone please give a explanation (a graph would be of great help) why it would move in a circle.

Comment: check the value of (x^2+(y-A)^2)

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions for x and y are just the recipes for the coordinates. You can put them together like this:

$$(x,y)=(\;A\sin(qt)\;\;,\;\;A-A\cos(qt)\;)$$

and then draw the points one by one by inserting different values of $t$.

### The circle-part

Let's start with the circle-part of this recipe:

$$(\;\sin(qt)\;\;,\;\;\cos(qt)\;)$$

This is a **circle**, and that will be clear when we remember how cosine and sine are defined:

- In a **unit circle**, cosine is the **horizontal** "distance" to a point on the perimeter, while sine is the **vertical** "distance" to that same point. Just like the x-coordinate is the horizontal and the y-coordinate the vertical distance to a point.

In the expression, the x-coordinates is *at all times* the sine and the y-coordinate *at all times* the cosine to whatever value of $qt$ you put in. No matter what value you input as $t$, **you get a point on the unit circle**.

So if you input all values between $0$ and one full round ($2\pi$ radians), then all the points of the unit circle will be drawn:

[image]

(Usually, it *must* be stated that for example $t\in[0;2\pi]$ - otherwise it could just as well have been a half-circle e.g. - but we'll assume that this is a full circle in your case.)

The value of $q$ in your given expression doesn't matter. It just causes the circle to be drawn "more times". If $q=2$, then the radians will range from $0$ to $4\pi$ and thus take *two* full rounds, because the $q$ doubles the values of $t$. Then you will have the circle drawn twice on top of itself. This makes no geometrical difference, but if this method is used to calculate the total length, then be aware that you have *double* length if $q=2$ (and in general a length $q$ times longer than the geometrical length).

### The radius-part

Multiplying something onto a unit circle will *stretch* it. Let's add the stretching part:

$$(\;A\sin(qt)\;\;,\;\;A\cos(qt)\;)$$

All points were the distance $1$ away from the centre, because it was a unit circle. By multiplying with $A$, you move them all $A$ times further away. This gives you a larger circle and $A$ is essentially the radius (I have set $A=2$ as an example):

[image]

Actually, it is not $A$ but $-A$ which is multiplied on to the y-coordinate:

$$(\;A\sin(qt)\;\;,\;\;-A\cos(qt)\;)$$

but that luckily only inverts the y-coordinates, which still gives the same circle (just drawn "flipped" or "bottom-first", which can't be seen).

If you wanted to make an ellipsis (a "squeezed" circle) in other situations, you would just stretch more in one direction than in the other, for example:

$$(\;2\sin(qt)\;\;,\;\;3\cos(qt)\;)$$

### The centre-part

Lastly, there was also something *added*:

$$(x,y)=(\;A\sin(qt)\;\;,\;\;A-A\cos(qt)\;)$$

A value $A$ was added to the y-coordinate. This only pushes all y-coordinates a fixed value upwards. It moves the whole circle upwards without distorting it (because the points are moved equally much and not relative to each other) ($A$ is still $2$ in this example, so the circle is moved up 2 units):

[image]

By adding something to the x- and y-coordinate, you can position your centre exactly as you want; move the circle around in your coordinate system.

### What is all this anyways?

This method of writing coordinates is called [parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrization).

It is a mathematical tool for simple modelling. And it is very effective also with more complex figures or figures in 2D or 3D as well, where one single $y=\text{something with }x$ function would not be enough to describe it.

A 1D-path (a curve) can always be parameterized into coordinate expressions with just 1 parameter, in this case the time $t$. 2D figures requires 2 (a plane or surface) and 3D figures require 3 parameters (a massive object; a body with volume).

As you see, this question is actually purely mathematical, because you are asking about the parameterization tool rather than the physics it shows. This tool or method can be used to describe and model many things in physics.